# Клиент получает ответ от сервера только при активной вкладке

Tags: php, javascript, сокет, websocket

Есть чат который работает на сокетах, все сокеты находятся в массиве. Нужна идея по реализации, пример: пользователь сидит в чате и получает все сообщения. Как только он перешел на другую вкладку, либо вообще свернул браузер, то сообщения перестают к нему приходить, как только вернулся в чат - сообщения приходят...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function (e) {
    if (document.hidden) {
        socket.message('away', {hidden: true});
    }
}, false);
```

И на сервере ловить событие away. А уж как на сервере реализовать мы без примера кода не поможем.

Comment: я так понимаю событие происходит после перехода на другую вкладку. Если это так, то что потом с этим событием на сервере делать?

Comment: Я же написал. Пока вы на сервер уведомление не отправите, он не узнает об этом.

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei Прошу прощение, не подскажите, какое событие должно срабатывать при первой загрузки страницы?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yarkov_aleksei/daxoeptj/